# How to create zoom bot which can join and record meeting using official zoom API or SDK way?

Tags: python, node.js, zoom-sdk

I want to create zoom bot which can join and record meeting using official way using zoom API or SDK.

I saw there exists [ZOOM API Reference](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/introduction/), [Zoom Meeting SDKs](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/introduction/) and [Meeting Bots: Accessing Media Streams](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/zoom-apps/guides/meeting-bots-sdk-media-streams/).
In [`ZOOM API Reference`](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/introduction/) I did not find anything using which I bot can join and record meeting.
In [`Zoom Meeting SDKs`](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/introduction/) I did not find anything which I can use in my [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) or [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) script for automation of joining and recording meeting.
In [`Meeting Bots: Accessing Media Streams`](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/zoom-apps/guides/meeting-bots-sdk-media-streams/) I found that its exists for Window and MacOS  so I am not sure if I can use it in my standalone python or node.js script.

So what is right API or SDK for creating bot which can join and record meeting?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, officially Zoom native (Windows, macOS) Meeting SDKs only support RAW Stream recording automation.

For that, you need to create Marketplace Meeting SDK App and download Native SDK and start building your bot. Once development is done then you need to get .exe or .dmg of your bot from the project and use docker to run multiple instances for multiple Meetings concurrently.

For more please review

- [Zoom Integration](https://www.youtube.com/@learnwithnak)
- [Zoom Devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/u/freelancer.nak/)
- [Zoom Bot Reviews on My profile](https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/%7E01fe42341856e68db9)